# Handling string encoding with the same code in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

I've got a [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/mediawiki-gateway) that's used a bunch of people using a bunch of different Ruby interpreters, and it includes what boils down to this code:

```
res = RestClient.post(...)
doc = REXML::Document.new(res).root
```

The content of `res` is always UTF-8, and this works fine in Ruby 1.8, but it blows up under Ruby 1.9 if the response is not pure ASCII *and* the user's default encoding is not UTF-8.

Now, if I wanted to make this work on Ruby 1.9 alone, I'd just stick `res.force_encoding('utf-8')` in there and be done with it, but that method is 1.9-only and then breaks under Ruby 1.8:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `force_encoding' for #<String:0x101318178>
```

The best solution can come up with is this, which forces the systemwide default encoding to UTF-8:

```
Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8' if defined? Encoding
```

Better ideas, or is this as good as it gets?  Will there be any negative impact on library users who are trying to use different encodings?

Comment: And to clarify, I can rely on the incoming content always being valid UTF-8.  The problem in Ruby 1.9 is that the String `res` is tagged with the user's default encoding, which may not be UTF-8, and this then causes REXML to barf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with Mike Lewis in using `respond_to`, but don't do it on the variable res everywhere throughout your code.

I took a look at [your code in gateway.rb](https://github.com/jpatokal/mediawiki-gateway/blob/master/lib/media_wiki/gateway.rb) and it looks like everywhere you are using `res`, it gets set by a call to `make_api_request` so you could add this before your return statement in that method:

```
doc = doc.force_encoding("UTF-8") if doc.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
```

Even if it's other places but it's not literally with every string you encounter, I'm sure you can find a way to refactor the code that makes sense and solves the problems in one place instead of everywhere you encounter it.

Are you having a problem with other places?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but that doesn't mean they don't exist...  but your solution is the best so far!

Answer (score 3):

```
  if res.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
    new_contents = res.force_encoding("UTF-8")
  else
    new_contents = res
  end
```

I'd do something like that for backwards compatibility.

Comment: But that's a terrible kludge, and I don't want to pollute every bit of my code that creates a string with things like that...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the snippet, the cause of the problem is `RestClient`, which doesn't return string in proper encoding (the one specified in HTTP response), so I'd first try to get that problem fixed. If that can't be done, then you could wrap `RestClient` calls with your code that forces the encoding (the way Mike Lewis suggested). Or you are experiencing the problem on places other than `RestClient` calls as well?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you include an `#encoding: utf-8` header in this particular file that uses this method.

Ruby 1.9 support different encodings throughout the application and should work fine if this content is utf-8 encoded.

Ruby 1.8 would simply ignore the `#encoding`header and keep on working nicely.

It's a very simple approach but i believe it deserves a try!

Comment: As far as I understand, the file header controls the source encoding, which is used only for strings in that source file (eg. `str = "Foo"`).  It has no impact on data acquired by I/O (eg. Restclient), whose default is set by the external encoding.  See http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings.